# Prime numbers without definitions and classes, just loops

Tags: ruby, primes

I am trying to input any number and check for prime numbers. I am trying to avoid classes and definitions. I am trying to use loops only. My code is listed below.

```
puts "What number would you like to find the largest prime factor?: "
lastnum = gets.to_i
puts "Number to find the largest prime factor is #{lastnum}"
n = 2
while (n <= lastnum)
  if n % 2 == 0
    puts "#{n} is not a prime"
  elsif n % Math.sqrt(n) == 0
    puts "#{n} is not a prime, sqrt rooted"
  else
    puts "#{n} is a prime"
  end
  n += 1
end
```

I get numbers such as `99` in my list of primes if I input `100`. Is there something I can add to or remove from my code? If there is an efficient way and I should get away from what I am doing, I shall consider that help as well.

Comment: Your code is far from checking for primes. It is only checking if a number is even or is divisible by its square root.

Comment: Your sentences `"What number ... the largest prime factor?"` and `"Number to ... the largest prime factor is ..."` are ungrammatical. They should be `"... the largest prime factor of ..."`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a largest_primes script without using methods.

```
input = 100
result = 2.upto(input - 1).select do |test_num|
  2.upto(test_num - 1).none? do |test_divider|
    (test_num % test_divider).zero?
  end
end.max

puts result
# => 97
```

Comment: There are 10 explicit and 1 implicit message sends, sending 8 (9) different messages, which will get dispatched to *at least* 8 (9) different methods in your code, possibly more. And that's counting only the message sends directly in your code, obviously any one of those methods will in turn call other methods which call other methods … and so on. "Without methods" is a bit of a stretch, I would say.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the highest range, upto you want to find highest prime no.

```
lastnum = 100
(1..lastnum).reverse_each do |num|
   if (2..num/2).none?{|i| num % i == 0}
     puts num
     break
   end
end
```

Here, we get highest range in **lastnum** var, we check for prime no. in descending order ( here 100 to 1 ) and divide that no. from 2 to half of that no. Whenever we get our first prime no. (highest) we stop our condition loop and return that highest prime number.